# Posting a form (the old way) with ng-click, is this bad practice?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, angularjs

I have been given a task by my boss who still likes things the old way... have a HTML page/view and submitting a form to a PHP page server side. We have introduced AngularJS to his app and he has the following code in his page:

```
<form name="rForm" id="rForm"  action="demo_form.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="quantity" id="reservationQuantity" ng-value="selectedQuantity"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="date" id="reservationDate" ng-value="selectedDate"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="time" id="reservationTime" ng-value="selectedTime"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="mId" id="mID" value="{{ $merchant->id }}" ng-value="mId"/>
</form>

<button>Go to next page...</button>
```

Now he wishes for us to have a link or button to submit this form which is outside the form, I believe that we should control all of this is a controller with all post functionality being handled by an injected / separate `$http` service. He doesn't believe me and says he knows best and I should just handle submitting the form like so

```
<button onclick="$('#reservationForm').submit();">Go to next page...</button>
```

I don't like this... however he pays the wages. Is there some way I can submit the form/page from my Angular controller and remove all that horrible jQuery code? Something like this (this won't work, I am just using this for visual purposes)

```
<button ng-click="ng-submit()">Go to next page...</button>
```

... and am I right saying that his method is bad practice and if we are going to submit to the server by pushing the page there's no point in us using an MVC framework.

Comment: Was it your choice or his to use AngularJS? If Angular JS plays a vital part in your web app it doesn't make sense to switch back to jquery.

Comment: @ babyfarkmcgeezax - that's what I thought. He wants to use AngularJS as much as me - he just doesn't understand it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can submit form through your Angular Controller. For this all you have to do is to call controller function in your ng-click like this:

```
<button ng-click="submit()">Go to next page...</button>
```

where submit() is your controller function. One more thing you need to assign ng-model to all form fields to access them in controller.

Comment: Thanks for that, I realise I can collect the form items and use $http to speak to the backend, I really mean can I use angular to push the whole page the server like we did in the dark days of internet programming